# Why an app is called even if the conditions are not met?

Tags: android, caching, broadcastreceiver, sms, listener

I have developed this simple app for listening for incoming SMS into my Android phone.

As you can see in the code, when a SMS arrives I scan its content for a specific text, so that if this condition is not met it does nothing further.

The real problem is, that when a SMS arrives and the conditions are not met, the IF statement created to control when to call the "maps" app or not is not executed, but the "maps" app is called either way, and loads the info related to the last SMS that met the conditions.

The code works perfectly in my emulator with KitKat, but in my phone with Kitkat 4.4.2 is working with the behavior I just wrote.

Have you faced something like this before? 
Can you throw me some light to solve this issue?

This is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText et_location_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt_manual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_manual);
    et_location_data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location_data);

    bt_manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messageBody = "";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                messageBody = et_location_data.getText().toString();
                Common_Functions common_functions = new Common_Functions(getBaseContext(), messageBody);
                common_functions.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    et_location_data.setText("");
}}
```

This is the Broadcast Listener

```
    public class SMS_listener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String messageBody= "";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {SmsMessage smsMessage = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)[0];
                messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            Common_Functions common_functions = new Common_Functions(context, messageBody);
            common_functions.show();
        }
        Log.d("Test", "Message body: " + messageBody);
    }
}}
```

This is a general use Class for code reuse

```
    public class Common_Functions {
String messageBody= "";
String STR_CODE_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
String STR_CODE_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
Context context;

String str_Lat = "";
String str_Lon = "";

public Common_Functions(Context context, String messageBody) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messageBody = messageBody;
}

public void show() {
    if (messageBody.toLowerCase().contains("Latitud".toLowerCase())) {
        int i = messageBody.toLowerCase().indexOf(STR_CODE_LATITUDE.toLowerCase());
        int j = messageBody.toLowerCase().indexOf(STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.toLowerCase());

        str_Lat = messageBody.substring(i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length(), i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length() + 10);
        str_Lon = messageBody.substring(j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length(), j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length() + 11);

        if (str_Lat.toLowerCase().contains("s"))
            str_Lat = "-" + messageBody.substring(i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length(), i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length() + 9);
        else
            str_Lat = messageBody.substring(i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length(), i + 1 + STR_CODE_LATITUDE.length() + 9);

        if (str_Lon.toLowerCase().contains("w"))
            str_Lon = "-" + messageBody.substring(j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length(), j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length() + 10);
        else
            str_Lon = messageBody.substring(j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length(), j + 1 + STR_CODE_LONGITUDE.length() + 10);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + str_Lat + "," + str_Lon));
        context.startActivity(intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

    }
}}
```

This is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMS_listener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="200">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: so are you saying you shouldnt always have the intent called? because currently thats what happens with what you have

Comment: Yes that is right. The intent should only be called when the SMS includes the text "latitud". And really it is called only when this condition is met, but I don't know why the "maps" app is still being called even when the conditions are not met .

Comment: what happens when you comment out the maps intent?

Comment: I did it just now and I get surprised, when the SMS I sent arrived, the "maps" app got called! That does not make any sense. It seems that there is something cached or something. I'll test again uninstalling and reinstalling the app with the Intent commented out.

Comment: so then the code you showed has nothing to do with the problem, search for the string `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=` in your project and see where else its used

Comment: Even uninstalling it and installing it back, with the Intent commented out, it still calls the "maps" app. It is very weird.

Comment: You are calling that intent somewhere else then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92761/discussion-between-runningwheels-and-tyczj).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I was facing with this app.

Since I have been making several tests before getting up to the final code I posted here, my phone seemed to be storing some weird information in cache, specifically for the "Messaging" process.

I realized this when I uninstalled the app completely and after that sent a SMS to my phone. Surprisingly, even with the app uninstalled, the "maps" app was still being called. That gave me the idea of clearing the cache for the "Messaging" process and Eureka, the problem was solved.

Experience for the future. But this behavior seems to be a big flaw with my version of Android 4.4.2 because I can't imaging that this OS can't manage that kind of threats.